# Why doesn't Google index the diameter sign ⌀

Tags: seo, google-search, unicode

I am using the diameter sign ⌀ in a few titles on my website but google did not index the sign, only skipped it and indexed the rest of the title.

But i saw that other sites us the Ø sign for diameter which is actually a vowel and a letter used in the Danish, Norwegian, Faroese, and Southern Sami languages. And google indexed that sign for their titles.

Should I just change the sign and us it wrong just to be indexed?

Comment: Most users don't search for ⌀ when looking for something that has a diameter. I dare to say that unless they are familiar with engineering/blueprints, many don't even know what that symbol means. Instead, they type "dia" or "diameter". So in addition to less language confusion for bots, it provides a more accurate result set for humans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ⌀ is a character used in foreign languages, if your page and title is in English but you are using ⌀ in your title, it's possible that you're confusing Googlebot's understanding of your page language.

To be on the safe side, I wouldn't make it a normal practice to use foreign characters that aren't in the language that you're writing in. That's not something you would commonly see in professional articles. If the foreign character is somehow essential to the title of your webpages, then I'd say go ahead and leave them in. If not, use an emoji instead if you just want to add some colors or pictures to your title.

Comment: I was using the sign for an online shop, because the title is limited in the number of characters i was trying to use the diameter sign ⌀ instead of writing "diameter".
I will change the titles so they can be understood by the bots.
Thank you

Comment: I see. I'm not familiar with diameter products so I'm not sure what that is. I can tell you though, Google has limitations in terms of understanding and searching for symbols. If you want to rank for diameter keywords you might be better off using "diameter" in the title instead of the symbol.